# Adding DIVs dynamically but keeping the container with fixed width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add `<div>some content</div>` dynamically to a container BUT I want this **container to have fixed height and width**, i.e., the added divs should scale themselves to fit in the container (thus also avoiding scroll bar in the container).

Setting the height of the container to 100% doesn't seem to work, since it scales to accomodade the div's.

It's more or less what jsfiddle.net does with those four iframes (e.g. try adjusting your window size).

Is there a way of accomplishing this by CSS?

example code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="added"> Some content </div>
<div class="added"> Some content </div>
</div>
```

style

```
#container { height: 100%; width: 100% }
.added { min-height: 200px; min-width: 200px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your `overflow` to `hidden`:

```
#container { height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle.net uses iframes you can use `overflow:scroll` in  `#container`, but `#container { height: 100%; width: 100% }` will depend of it parent element, so you can make:

```
#container { height: 500px; width: 200px; overflow:scroll }
```

Answer (score 0):

why not reverse it? you say you want the container to have fixed height and width, but then you make it to have dynamic height and width.

```
#container { height: 500px; width: 500px } // or whatever
.added { height: 50%; width: 50%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#container { height: 500px; width: 200px; position: relative; overflow: hidden }
.added { position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```